# Trouble loading Custom Controller with Suscriber

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have been trying to implement my own controller for a 6 wheel robot. I have been using various examples to implement the code, notably the Valkyrie and Packt tutorials, as well as the diff_drive_controller. I am running ROS_Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 on a Jetson TX2. Using gazebo for the robot simulation.

When adding the suscribe line "sub_command_ = n.subscribe("/ground_truth/state", 1, &Controller_6202::ground_truth_Callback, this);" , the launch file fails to load the controller with the error:

```
[ERROR] [1607403971.165081452, 0.381000000]: Could not load class 'controller_6202_ns/Controller_6202': Failed to load library /home/polyorbite/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libcontroller_6202_lib.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/polyorbite/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libcontroller_6202_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18controller_6202_ns15Controller_620221ground_truth_CallbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEE) [ERROR] [1607403971.165271469, 0.381000000]: Could not load controller 'controller_6202_name' because controller type 'controller_6202_ns/Controller_6202' does not exist
```

This is the cpp file implementation for the callback

```
//Ground_truth_Callback
void ground_truth_Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{

    [...]
}   
//Controller initialization
bool Controller_6202::init(hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface* hw, ros::NodeHandle &n)
{
    effortJointHandles.clear();

    //Retrieve the joint object to control
    std::vector<std::string> jointNames;
    
    
    if(n.getParam("joints", jointNames))
    {   
        if(hw)
        {
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < jointNames.size(); ++i)
            {
                //Ici, les roues gauches sont aux positions 0 à 3
                effortJointHandles.push_back(hw->getHandle(jointNames[i]));
            }

            buffer_command_effort.resize(effortJointHandles.size(), 0.0);
            buffer_current_positions.resize(effortJointHandles.size(), 0.0);
            buffer_current_velocities.resize(effortJointHandles.size(), 0.0);
            buffer_current_efforts.resize(effortJointHandles.size(), 0.0);
      }
      else
      {
          ROS_ERROR("Effort Joint Interface is empty in hardware interace.");
          return false;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      ROS_ERROR("No joints in given namespace: %s", n.getNamespace().c_str());
      return false;
   }

//Suscribe to ground truth
sub_command_ = n.subscribe("/ground_truth/state", 1, &Controller_6202::ground_truth_Callback, this);

return true;
}
```

When the suscribe line is removed, there is no error and the controller seems to work fine (without the subscription to the ground truth of course.

sub_command_ and ground_truth_Callback have both been defined in the .h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <controller_interface/controller.h>
#include <hardware_interface/joint_command_interface.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <ros/node_handle.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>

namespace controller_6202_ns {

    class Controller_6202: public controller_interface::Controller<hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface>
    {
    public:
        //Controller_6202();
        //virtual ~Controller_6202();
        bool init(hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface* hw, ros::NodeHandle &n);
        void update(const ros::Time& time, const ros::Duration& period);
        void starting(const ros::Time& time);
        void stopping(const ros::Time& time);
        
        void ground_truth_Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
        double * getTorque(const ros::Duration& period);

    private:
        std::vector<hardware_interface::JointHandle> effortJointHandles;
        std::vector<double> buffer_command_effort;
        std::vector<double> buffer_current_positions;
        std::vector<double> buffer_current_velocities;
        std::vector<double> buffer_current_efforts;
        //double u;
        //double v;
        //double r;
        ros::Subscriber sub_command_;
    };
}
```

My package.xml has these included:

```
    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>controller_interface</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>controller_interface</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>pluginlib</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>controller_interface</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>pluginlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>

  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
        <controller_interface plugin="${prefix}/controller_plugins.xml" />

  </export>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(controller_6202)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  controller_interface
  pluginlib
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  tf
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS src 
    LIBRARIES controller_6202  
    CATKIN_DEPENDS pluginlib roscpp
  DEPENDS Boost
)

add_library( controller_6202_lib src/controller_6202.cpp )
target_link_libraries( controller_6202_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

With "rospack plugins --attrib=plugin controller_interface", my controller is defined, I can also see it using "rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types"

Since the "suscribe" line is the only one causing the problem, I am assuming that it is causing the init to crash and not returning true. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance! Please tell me if any additional informations are required.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367190/trouble-loading-custom-controller-with-suscriber/) by [ofx](https://answers.ros.org/users/64888/ofx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-08**:
This is a linker error. Are you linking to all required libraries?

**Comment by [ofx](https://answers.ros.org/users/64888/ofx/) on 2020-12-08**:
What do you mean by linking to all required libraries? I have added the packages "std_msgs" and "nav_msgs" to both CMakeLists.txt (find_package) and package.xml (build_depend and exec_depend)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-13**:
@ofx can you please update your question with your `CMakeLists.txt` file?

**Comment by [ofx](https://answers.ros.org/users/64888/ofx/) on 2020-12-13**:
Updated!
I have just tried changing the message type to geometry_msg_twist, and it does not work either, with the message changed to:

```
libcontroller_6202_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18controller_6202_ns15Controller_620221ground_truth_CallbackERKN13geometry_msgs6Twist_ISaIvEEE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The implementation for you Callback is missing the class prefix:

```
//Ground_truth_Callback
void ground_truth_Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
```

should be

```
//Ground_truth_Callback
void Controller_6202::ground_truth_Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
```

This is why the linker reports and undefined symbol. It is looking inside the class, but there is no implementation of the function.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ofx](https://answers.ros.org/users/64888/ofx/) on 2020-12-14**:
Can't believe I missed it! Thanks it works now.